# Celery, RabbitMQ removes worker from consumers list while it is performing tasks

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I have started my celery worker, which uses RabbitMQ as broker, like this:

```
celery -A my_app worker -l info -P gevent -c 100 --prefetch-multiplier=1 -Q my_app
```

Then I have task which looks quite like this:

```
@shared_task(queue='my_app', default_retry_delay=10, max_retries=1, time_limit=8 * 60)
def example_task():
    # getting queryset with some filtering
    my_models = MyModel.objects.filter(...)

    for my_model in my_models.iterator():
        my_model.execute_something()
```

Sometimes this task can be fininshed less than a minute and sometimes, during highload, it requires more than 5 minutes to finish.

The main problem is that RabbitMQ constantly removes my worker from consumers list. It looks really random. Because of that I need to restart worker again.

Workers also starts throwing these errors:

```
SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2396)
```

Sometimes these errors:

```
consumer: Cannot connect to amqps://my_app:**@example.com:5671/prod: SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)').

Couldn't ack 2057, reason:"RecoverableConnectionError(None, 'connection already closed', None, '')"
```

I have tried to add `--without-heartbeat` but it does nothing.

How to solve this problems? Sometimes my tasks takes more than 30 minutes to finish, and I can't constantly monitor if workers were kicked out from rabbitmq.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone having these issues in the future this seems to be an issue with RabbitMQ. I tried Redis and the issue goes away. I wanted to stick with RabbitMQ for production though so I tried [LavinMQ](https://lavinmq.com/) which is a drop in replacement and changed my queue from gevent to solo with one worker per server and the issues disappeared.

Comment: When you tried Redis (and it worked), did you use gevent as well?